# Wordpress - Ayuda con bordes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

estoy necesitando ayuda con mi pagina de wordpress.
http://mercadocentraltest.com/

En la imagen del cuerpo, cuyo texto dice "del campo a tu casa", tengo dificultades para quitar los bordes de los costados. Quisiera que la imagen esté completamente expandida hacia los bordes.

Estuve revisando inspeccionando el codigo con google chrome y vi que estaria bajo el id = content y la clase = site-content, pero no se como corregir esto... y tambien, si lo que identifique es correcto.

Gracias y buen dia.

Comment: Seria muy util, que añadieras tu codigo y nos muestres lo que has hecho, y las pruebas y errores que has obtenido durante el camino a resolver tus dudas, con ellos podremos ayudarte de una manera mas optima, saludos.

Comment: Hola Ivan, aun no he metido mano en el codigo, nomas con el inspector del google chrome. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ingresa al `style.css` de tu template y modifica los siguientes valores:

**Antes:**

```
.entry-content, .entry-summary {
    padding: 0 10% 10%;
}
```

**Para que se pegue solo a los costados:**

```
.entry-content, .entry-summary {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

**Para que se pegue a los costados y abajo:**

```
.entry-content, .entry-summary {
    padding: 0;
}
```

De esta forma estas diciendo que no haya "relleno" dentro del `<div class="entry-content">`.

Te recomiendo ver artículos como [este](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) que te van a ser de mucha utilidad.